# Cannot Bridge Edge Loops Without Messing Up Normals/Smooth-Shading?

Tags: modeling

I'm still kind of a beginner at modeling in Blender. I'm making a simple wine glass mesh, with an offset inner wall (for glass thickness) that I made manually. The top of the wine glass therefore has two close edge loops (rings).[image] I want to bridge them somehow and make faces to connect the inner and outer layers of the glass. But using Bridge Edge Loops messes up the previously consistent and smooth shading. Even if I try manually filling in each face individually, it still creates inconsistent shading on the top ring of polygons that create the edge rings at the top. [image]
I tried hollowing out a basic cylinder, creating an inner wall, and bridging both walls, and the shading remained consistent. What am I missing with regards to the wine glass? I tried recalculating and flipping normals, but no changes.

Comment: Either add an *Edge Split* modifier to your object, or turn on auto smooth in your mesh under the *Properties Window > Object Data > Normals > Auto Smooth*

Comment: Thank you very much, turning on Auto Smooth seems to do the trick!